# Linq multiple group by and joins

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables in this hierarchy:

```
Table1 [1 to many]
   --> Table2 [1 to many]
          --> Table3 [many]
```

I would like to achieve:

```
var finalResult = (List<TableResult1>)linqQuery.ToList(); 

public class TableResult1
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<TableResult2> ListTableResult2 { get; set; }
}
public class TableResult2
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<TableResult3> ListTableResult3 { get; set; }
}
public class TableResult3
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the models:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Table1Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Table3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can join everything then group by Table1 but that's as far as I can go.

Any help with an example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you:

I wrote the original query against some of my entities, and then went through and renamed them to your Table1/2/3 - I might have missed something, so there may be a syntax error or two, but it should work

```
var table3Join =
    Table2
    .GroupJoin(
        Table3,
        ttwo => ttwo.Id,
        tthree => tthree.Table2Id,
        (ttwo, tthree) => new { ttwo = ttwo , tthree = tthree }
    );

var sqlQuery = 
    Table1
    .GroupJoin(
        table3Join, 
            tone => tOne.Id,
            twwo => twwo.ttwo.Table1Id,
            (tone, ttwo) => new { tone = tone, ttwo = ttwo }
    ).ToList();

var tableResults = sqlQuery.Select(r => new TableResult1
{
    Key = r.tone.Id,
    ListTableResult2 = r.ttwo.Select(ttwo => new TableResult2
    {
        Key = ttwo.ttwo.Id,
        ListTableResult3 = ttwo.tthree.Select(tthree => new TableResult3
        {
            Key = tthree.Id
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to see a single query but this works great! Thanks!

Comment: You definitely can put it in one query - it just might look a bit messy - you should be able to replace `table3Join` with the first query, and replace `sqlQuery` with the second

Comment: @JasonFoglia Also - the above, even with seperate parts, will only hit the database once - if that's what you're concerned about